# Error installing Network driver

Tags: windows-7, networking, drivers

I'm tring to install [NetLimiter 3](http://www.netlimiter.com/) (3.0.0.10, x64) on my Windows 7 x64 machine.

At the driver installation step, I'm getting an error:

```
Error 0x8004a029: Couldn't install the network component. (InstallNdisIMDriver)
```

**UPDATE 2010-09-20:**
I received a response to my support request:

> Hi Simon,
>
> It seems that problem is rather on your
>   system than in NL3. Too many
>   networking applications (VPN, Virtual
>   computers) are installed on your
>   machine and they are preventing NL3
>   from proper installation. In order to
>   install NetLimiter 3, try to
>   disable/temporarily remove these apps.
>   Several users had the same problem and
>   shuffling with adapter and networking
>   software helped them.  Please, let us
>   know which action helps you (if any).
>
> Sincerely,  Jan Bilek

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: What version did you download?

Comment: There are separate downloads for 32-bit and 64-bit systems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After having the same issue while trying to install NL I found the following info, which solved my problem.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2011/02/21/windows-7-service-pack-1-fails-with-error-code-0x8004a029.aspx

> Option 1
>
> Windows 7 is hard coded to allow 14
>   filter drivers, but the following
>   registry sets the limit to 8 by
>   default.  You can adjust the amount up
>   to 14 or delete this key and it will
>   be set to max of 14.
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\MaxNumFilters

Comment: Thanks for the taking the time to post here! At first I thought something like this might be the issue but couldn't find anything about it. I indeed had a LOT of filter drivers installed at the time.

Comment: I have had this exact same problem installing Shrew Soft VPN Client, and this solution resolved it.

Comment: Also helpful for resolving an issue installing Windows Virtual PC when I already had VirtualBox and a third-party VPN. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [most recent version 64 bit](http://www.netlimiter.com/download/nl3setup-x64.exe), then the place to ask this question is from Netlimiter Support at `support@netlimiter.com`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the most recent x64 version and I already emailed them about the issue. I have not received a response from them yet.

Comment: Did you try running the installer as Administrator?

Comment: Yes, the installer asked for admin privileges right at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled VMware, Broadcom Diagnostics, Intel MyWifi and it seems [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/) is the culprit.

I was able to install NetLimiter once Connectify was gone.